# PrestShop: How can i make the product dissapear automatically when quantity becomes less than 2?

Tags: prestashop-1.6, product-quantity

I want is when the quantity of product becomes less than or equal to 2 - it should automatically disable or dissapear from front-end and when we increase the quantity to any number greater than 2 - it should auomatically appear on front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (using CRON)

```
    $link = mysql_connect('Serveur_MySQL', 'Identifiant', 'Mot_de_passe');
    if (!$link) {
        die('No connection possible: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('Nom_de_la_database');

    mysql_query('UPDATE ps_product_shop SET active=0 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE quantity<=2)');
    mysql_query('UPDATE ps_product_shop SET active=1 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE quantity>2)');
```

Check table prefix, prefer use class db (more safe, more useful) :
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices

Comment: is this a MySql trigger or cron job ? Where do i have to place this code?

Comment: This code is used as a standalone php script. So you can call it from url. Creating a CRON allow you to launch this script whenever you want. Basically, if php file is located in www.MyDomain.tld/scripts/MyScript.php, you can launch it from CRON, there is a module in Prestashop for that (Prestashop CRON i guess).